# Declare a Variable that can be used across Multiple Forms

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering if there is a simple way to declare a variable on one form which can then be used on multiple separate forms. I have seen the suggestion:

```
Public Variable_Name As String
```

but it does not seem to work despite placing it in a public class and having the code referencing Variable_Name also in a public class. If anyone has any suggestions that they know will work, it would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
Code on Form 1:

```
Public Class WithdrawFunds
    Public Funds As String = "0"

Public Sub Button_Withdraw_20_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button_Withdraw_20.Click
    Static Funds As String = "$20"
    Dim SlideCheckout As New Checkout
    SlideCheckout.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

End Class

Code on Form 2:

```
Public Class Checkout

Public Sub Checkout_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label_Amount.Text = WithdrawFunds.Funds
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Easy way is to make it static https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx (but that is considered bad practice). You should consider dependency injection, but that might be a little overreach to start with.

Comment: I have just tried that and it doesn't seem to work either. Code:
        Static Funds As String = "$20"
        Label_Amount.Text = Funds
It says that Funds is not declared, and i assume that is because they are coded on separate forms. I may have misunderstood your suggestion though.

Comment: Prefix the "Funds" with the name of the form where the variable is declared.

Comment: For clarification what is meant by Marvin's comment: for instance `Label_Amount.Text = Form1.Funds`

Comment: I have updated the post to show both of you the code i currently have, it is yet to work (give me $20 when button is pressed), however i do receive 0 in the label now, which is an improvement from my previous attempts. I apologies if i have misinterpreted your instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a Module:

```
Public Module MyVariables
    Public Funds As String = "0"
End Module

Public Class WithdrawFunds
    Public Sub Button_Withdraw_20_Click( ... )
         MyVariables.Funds = "$20"
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Checkout   
    Public Sub Checkout_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label_Amount.Text = MyVariables.Funds
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if solved it bot i think you are using two Funds variables 
you should try like this

```
Public Class WithdrawFunds
  Public Funds As String = "0"

Public Sub Button_Withdraw_20_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button_Withdraw_20.Click
  Funds = "$20" 
    Dim SlideCheckout As New Checkout
    SlideCheckout.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Good luck XD